# What does "...how good you have it" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> - You don't know **how good you have** it.
> - Realize **how good you have it.**

How and when to use these phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually used when expressing that someone does not appreciate what they have. It has a kinda complaining tone to it.

Eg. Adam has every iPhone up until iPhone 6, but his parents refuse to buy him the iPhone 7. He complains about how hard his life is because he doesn't have the latest iPhone. He also is able to but chooses not to work as his parents own a business.

Adam's mum works hard and spends hours maintaining their business, in order to sustain their luxurious life style. She tells him, "You don't know how good you have it." - Adam's mum is indicating that Adam doesn't appreciate what he has (the iphones up until iPhone 6) and the hard work required to earn money and buy the iPhones.

Note: this is a fake scenario, I have nothing against people who buy lots of iPhones